# When storing results of API request in state object, can't access data in object

Tags: javascript, api, constructor, promise, async-await

Here is just a small piece of code to illustrate my problem. I want to store the data in the state object and access the data through the state object. But when I log the state object to the console I see all the data, when trying to access the data properties I get an undefined?

```
var state = {}
var weather = new Weather('Boston')

var getResults = async () => {
    await weather.getData()
    console.log(weather)
    state.result = weather
}
getResults()

console.log(state)        ------------------> logs all the data
console.log(state.result)   ------------------> undefined
```

Comment: `getResults` is async. You can't read the values it sets until after it has run. (`console.log` has lazy evaluation of objects, it doesn't check the contents of the object you are logging until you explicitly look at it (which will be after the async function has finished).

Comment: It should be console.log(state.result) . ???

Comment: Also what @Quentin said above.
getResults itself is asynchronous in nature. So firstly that should be executed and then you must console.log

Comment: You are right should be state.result but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: It works like this: getResults().then( result => console.log(state.result.data)) Or when logging it within the async function. You can only process the data within the async functions body or in the then() callback